# What algorithm can I use to compute 2022^n (given n \in N)? How can I prove the correctness (maybe induction?) and what's the upper bound used?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, discrete-mathematics, induction

I have to use n-1 multiplications but I am confused about proving the correctness of the algorithm and finding the upper bound.
How do I do/show that??

I know 2022 = 20*(100+1)+2

2022 = 2000+20+2  ......
2022 = 2000+2+2+..+2
etc.

Comment: Can you write an expression for 2022^n simply ?

Comment: If you have to use n-1 multiplication then you can just do it the naive way. Otherwise check out exponentiation by squaring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are breaking 2022 into additions. `m^n` means to multiply `m` by itself `n` times, e.g.:

> 2022^n = 2022 * 2022 * ... * 2022.

Note 2022 appears `n` times (this is the definition of raising a number to a power), and there are `n-1` multiplication operations.

For example, `2022^2 = 2022 * 2022`. There is one multiplication operation.

You can accomplish this in code like this (C# here, but the concept applies to every language):

```
long m = 2022;
long n = 3;

long counter = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  counter = counter * m;
  
Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

Note that raising 2022 to even a modestly large value for n will overflow 64-bit integer types. You can still get a good approximation for larger n using floating point types.

As mentioned in the comments, a more efficient but less obvious approach is [exponentation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).